# What is the cardinality of $\{{(x, y) \in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \mid x-y \,\text{ is even}}\}$?

Tags: functions, cardinals

I've been trying to find it by searching for a one-on-one function
$$f:\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \mid x-y \,\text{ is   even}\} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$$
and an onto function:
$$g:\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \mid x-y \,\text{ is   even}\} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$$ 
to prove that $$\bigl|\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \mid x-y \,\text{ is   even}\}\bigr| = |\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}|$$

I found $f((x, y)) = (x, y)$, but can't find a proper $g$.
Can a single function have two outputs for a single input?
For example: $g((x, y)) = (x, y),\space(x, y + 1)$?

Thanks!

Comment: A function has only one output for a given input

Comment: Can you use CSB (=Cantor Schroder-Bernstein) theorem?

Comment: This is an instance where it may be easier to come up with a proof for a more general statement. Try to prove the following instead: If $|A| = |\mathbb N|$, and $B\subset A$ is an infinite subset, then also $|B|=|\mathbb N|$.

Comment: For $g$ what's wrong with $(x,y)\mapsto (x, |y-x|/2)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The smaller infinite cardinal is the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$ (the countable infinity). It is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.

As your set is a subset of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, its cardinal is at most infinite countable. But as it is infinite, it is at least infinite countable. Thus its cardinality is infinite countable.

Another more rigorous proof would use Cantor-Bernstein theorem : find an injective function of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ to your subset and an injective function from your subset to $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. I propose the following. Say your subset is $A$, and

\begin{align}
f : A &\to \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \\
(x,y) &\mapsto (x,y)
\end{align}
is the natural injection, and
\begin{align}
g : \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} & \to  A \\
(x,y) & \mapsto (x+y,x-y) \text{ if } x> y \\
(x,y) & \mapsto (y-x, x+y) \text{ if} x \leqslant y 
\end{align}
Show that $g$ is injective (it is easy) and well defined (because$ (x+y)-(x-y) = 2x$ and $(y-x)-(x+y) = -2x$ are even).

Comment: Can I just use $(x, y) \mapsto (x + y, |x - y|)$? Thanks!

Comment: I edited. Using just $|x-y|$ would make it symmetric in $x$ and $y$, thus non-injective. I think my edit outpass this problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bijection from $A$ to $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$:
$$(x, y) \mapsto \begin{cases}\left(x, \dfrac{y+1}{2}\right) & y \text{ is odd}\\
\left(x, \dfrac{y}{2}\right) & y \text{ is even}\\\end{cases}$$

The verification that this is a bijection is not too hard.
(Keep in mind that if $(x, y) \in A$ and $y$ is odd, then  $x$ is odd as well. Same for being even.)